# Manage User Redirect Spring Security

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

i'm new to spring security can any one guide me how to do this. my configuration class of spring security is mention below: i made my home page "/" visible to all user. so i didn't use "/" in http.antmatchs("/") in home page my nav bar has link for "login and signup". after successful login user redirect to "buyer/list" endpoint  which i mention in configuration. **what i want is "login user" can't visit homepage again.** for this i also use

```
Object principal = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getPrincipal();
```

for "/" mapping controller, but it throw nullPointerException. can any one guide me how do i proceed. if there is other approach please mention.

```
Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecureConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Value("${winni.auth.exit}")
    private String authExit;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        http.requestMatchers()
                .antMatchers("/login", "/web/**", "/action/**", "/cart/**", "/cart/xhr/**", "/buyer/**","/profile/**","/chat/**","/order/**")
                .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/buyer/list", true).permitAll().and()
                .logout().logoutSuccessUrl(authExit);
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/assets/**");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want that only unauthenticated users can access "/" and "/login" and only authenticated users on the other pages. I would do something like this:

```java
http
  .authorizeRequests()
  .antMatchers("/web/**", "/action/**", "/cart/**", "/cart/xhr/**", "/buyer/**","/profile/**","/chat/**","/order/**")
    .authenticated()
  .and()
  .antMatchers("/", "/login")
    .anonymous()
  .and()
  .formLogin().loginPage("/login")
    .defaultSuccessUrl("/buyer/list", true)
  .and()
  .logout()
    .logoutSuccessUrl("/");
```

Comment: i try your code my login page show error...
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Wed Apr 15 12:31:52 IST 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
No message available. 

i also want if loged in user want to access this url then it redirect to other page "/buyer/list"

Comment: My mistake, by copying/pasting your code I didn't see that the login page was set for authenticated users. It should be  set for anonymous users only. I'll modify my answer.

Comment: i just did it.by some changes
http.authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/login").defaultSuccessUrl("/buyer/list", true).permitAll().and()
                .logout().logoutSuccessUrl(authExit);

and in contoller 

@RequestMapping("/")
    public String sayHello(Principal principal) {

        if (principal != null) {
            return "redirect:/buyer/list";
        } else {
            return "pub/home";
        }
    }
i use principle to check is null